# php.in E212: Can’t Open File for Writing error

Tags: pi-4

On my Raspberry Pi 4 in Terminal I edited /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini to resolve some other issues I am having, and when I use :wq! to save and exit I receive the following error:

**`"/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini" "/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini" E212: Can't open file for writing Press ENTER or type command to continue`**

I searched google and found some posts about the issue, but I didn't understand them. They were quite complicated. Just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction if they have the time to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system files are generally owned by `root` and you need special permission to edit them.  `sudo` gives you this permission.

Rather than `vi filepath` use `sudo vi filepath`

Comment: It is preferable to use sudedit rather than inflict the trauma of vi on new users.

Comment: @Milliways The OP was editing with vi so I went with the flow.

Comment: Thanks for answering my noob questions. This worked, thanks again.